# How do i show/hide page content depending on the users role?

Tags: nodes, users

I am creating a site that has several roles.  When some one who is logged in goes to a certain page I want the page to determine what content needs to be displayed depending on what roll they are.

Example.  If the user is attached to the "teacher" role then they will see "Hello **teacher** thank you for visiting our site" then it might have two buttons that leads them to certain pages.  If they are attached to the "student" role they will see "Hello **student** thank you for visiting our site" then the two buttons would be different and lead them some where else.

Is there a module that could help with this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two good ways you could go about this.

1. Install [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and
   enable Page manager. Panels has a huge collection of what are called
   'visibility rules' for individual panes. These allow you extremely
   fine grained control over who sees what portion of the page. Panels
   offers a lot of power, but brings a lot of complexity along with it.
2. Put your messages each in their own block. Blocks come with the ability to show and hide for certain roles.
   This method is much simpler, but if you have a lot more content than just
   the welcome message you want to show and hide panels
   will end up being a more customizable solution.